# Comparison of standard reducing potential of Co3+ and Mn3+

Tags: reduction-potential

$\ce{Co^3+(aq) + e- → Co^2+(aq)}$   +1.81 V

$\ce{Mn^3+(aq) + e- → Mn^2+(aq)}$ +1.51 V

This is the data of Standard reducing potentials I have found on internet. Why is reducing potential of $\ce{Mn^3+}$ is less than that of $\ce{Co^3+}$. $\ce{Mn^3+}$ converts to $\ce{Mn^2+}$ which is half filled configuration and hence more stable. Am I missing something?

Comment: The answer is simple, you are overlooking the most important trend in the 3d block. Everybody likes to think about the fancy stuff like exchange energy, Jahn-Teller effects, blah blah blah but they forget that **effective nuclear charge increases going across the 3d block**.